# String matching /comparing with another set of string with different **combination** in Mysql 5.0/C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, string, performance, linq

I have **some strings**, for example:

**string 1 :** I want to see my **friend**

**string 2:** My **friend** has a red **pen** and yellow **box**

**string 3:** This yellow **box** belongs to my **friend**

**string 4:** He is a doctor

etc....

I want to compare these strings with another **string : pen box friend**  and should get result at first **string2**, then **string 3** and then **string1**

**please help me**. I want to know how it should be done. The way I am thinking is a very time consuming method.Is there any simple method to do so whatever be the logic. I want it to done in **any** of the following: **Mysql5.0 or C# or LINQ**

Comment: For what reasons string 3 should come after string2?

Comment: What have you tried? Check out the string class methods: `String.Split` and `String.Contains`. That will help you.

Comment: @Steve:i have updated the new one..there was small miss understanding while making string 2 bold.now i think u understood what i mean(string 2 have maximum matching than string 3)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel:if we split **string**,we have to apply various combination of splitted string against string1,string2,...string'n' and ordering the one's with max hit is very tiresome process especialy if we have large 'n' no. of strings.By using just `String.Split` and `String.Contains` will be having low performance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var searchTerms = Comparate.Split(' ');
var results = inputs
    .GroupBy(sentence => sentence.Split(' '))
    .Where(grouping => searchTerms.Intersect(grouping.Key).Any())
    .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Key.Count())
    .SelectMany(grouping => grouping);
```

Contextual usage:

```
var inputs = new[] {
    "I want to see my friend", 
    "My friend has a red pen and yellow box",
    "This yellow car belongs to my friend",
    "He is a doctor"
};
const string Comparate = "pen box friend";

var searchTerms = Comparate.Split(' ');
var results = inputs
    .GroupBy(sentence => sentence.Split(' '))
    .Where(grouping => searchTerms.Intersect(grouping.Key).Any())
    .OrderByDescending(grouping => grouping.Key.Count())
    .SelectMany(grouping => grouping);

foreach (var result in results)
    Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: :thanks alot..i got what i was looking for.I should check the performance for large set for this.Make the 3rd statement ""This yellow box belongs to my friend" instead of ""This yellow car belongs to my friend".I am sorry,it was a small mistake done while i made the question in hurry.But you have given perfect answer..thanks alot..keep it up

Comment: Is there any query for this in mysql??.thanks in advance..